# How to create a cluster of related entries in a many-to-many-relation?

Tags: sql, many-to-many, recursive-query

I have a table of subscription users, with a contact ID and order ID. Multiple contacts can be linked to one order and a contact can be linked to multiple orders. I'm trying to take a given order, look at the users for that order, identify any other orders any of those users are associated with, and link them as one company as the table shows:

[image: image of desired output]

Comment: I think, what you are looking for is impossible to do in one SQL query. First of all, because I don't think there is a way to tell SQL to automatically name your companies. If you avoid this, you would probably start with one entry, look for all the contacts in that company, take another entry without a company and repeat this until you have no entries without a company left.
But even then, I think you would need some sort of recursion to solve your problem. A suggestion:

Comment: ``SELECT DISTINCT contactID FROM a WHERE orderID IN
(SELECT orderID FROM a WHERE contactID IN 
(SELECT contactID FROM a WHERE orderID = 5))``

Comment: Thanks for your help with this Jere

Answer (score 0):

Apparently I was wrong and SQL does provide a way to solve your problem. Here is my solution. It is not optimized regarding the runtime efficiency - if that's necessary, I could take another look at it:

```
with recursive 
    incompany(contact, order1, order2) 
        as (select contact, o1.orderID as order1, o2.orderID as order2 
            from orders o1 join orders o2 using (contact) 
            union 
            select o1.contact, inc.order1, o2.orderID as order2 
            from incompany as inc, orders as o1, orders as o2 
            where inc.order2=o1.orderID and o1.contact=o2.contact) 

select contact, sum(order1) as MyNewCompanyID from 
    (select distinct contact, order1 from incompany) as foo 
    group by contact;
```

In the first part, I am defining a recursive query `incompany`, that does most of the work and assigns every `orderID` that is used by another contact in the same company to that contact. So `select * from incompany;` in itself would return the following table:

```
+---------+--------+--------+
| contact | order1 | order2 |
+---------+--------+--------+
| a       |      1 |      1 |
| a       |      1 |      2 |
| a       |      2 |      1 |
| a       |      2 |      2 |
| a       |      3 |      1 |
| a       |      3 |      2 |
| b       |      1 |      1 |
| b       |      2 |      1 |
| b       |      3 |      1 |
| c       |      1 |      1 |
| c       |      2 |      1 |
| c       |      3 |      1 |
| d       |      1 |      2 |
| d       |      1 |      3 |
| d       |      2 |      2 |
| d       |      2 |      3 |
| d       |      3 |      2 |
| d       |      3 |      3 |
| e       |      4 |      4 |
| e       |      4 |      5 |
| e       |      5 |      4 |
| e       |      5 |      5 |
| f       |      4 |      4 |
| f       |      5 |      4 |
| g       |      4 |      5 |
| g       |      5 |      5 |
+---------+--------+--------+
```

The second part of the query basically just shortens this table to the necessary minimum and then creates a new kind of "company ID" (`MyNewCompanyID`) as the sum of all the orders, this company uses. With your example, it returns the following table:

```
+---------+----------------+
| contact | MyNewCompanyID |
+---------+----------------+
| a       |              6 |
| b       |              6 |
| c       |              6 |
| d       |              6 |
| e       |              9 |
| f       |              9 |
| g       |              9 |
+---------+----------------+
```

## What the `with` part does

In the first part, I am defining something like a temporary view, that I can later access like a regular table. Inside, it has to consist of a regular query first, unioned by a second query, that is allowed to recursively access itself.

If you want to know more about this kind of recursion, I recommend these two videos:

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Yceqbp_DKbA
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uU7JBM3cAWU

## Edit

To assign a unique number each company, you should probably rather use `row_number()` as explained here: https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-window-functions/sql-server-row_number-function/